# VBA If cell equals “” Name " then sort

Tags: vba, excel

I'm  new to [vba](/questions/tagged/vba). I need someone with  more experience to look at this for like 4 seconds to educate me. :)

My problem is the first part is good (as seen below). Based on the names in the cell D5, (like Don, or Keith) I want the sorting to occur. For this first part it works.

**this part works**

```
Sheets("Input Tab").Select 
Range("D5").Select
If Selection.Value = "Don" Then

Sheets("Cost Center Comparison").Range("$A$5:$P$815").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array("10" _
    , "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "20", "21", "30", "51", "52", "54", "55", "57", "58", "60"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

**issues with `ElseIf` here**

Then I want to go back to that same cell (D5) to continually evaluate it. If the name changes, so will the filter.

```
 ElseIf Sheets("Input tab").Range("D5").Selection.Value = "Job/Bob" Then
 Sheets("Cost Center Comparison").Range("$A$5:$P$815").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array("12"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

The `ElseIf` for some reason doesn't work, and I don't understand the syntax well enough to know why. Any help?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work"?  Computer blows up?  Wrong Answer? Error message (if so, what message)? etc.  Also, I see where your code filters, but I don't see any place where it is sorting.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work better for you...

```
Sub FilterOnName()    
    Dim nm As String, arr As Variant    
    nm = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Input Tab").Range("D5").Value

    Select Case nm
        Case "Don": arr = Array("10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", _
                                "20", "21", "30", "51", "52", "54", _
                                "55", "57", "58", "60")

        Case "Job/Ron": arr = Array("12")        
        'Case Else: define a default here if no match
    End Select

    If Not IsEmpty(arr) Then        
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Cost Center Comparison").Range("$A$5:$P$815") _
               .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=arr, Operator:=xlFilterValues        
    End If        
End Sub
```

Comment: Tim Williams. You are a jedi of excel vba and I want to study at your feet. It's stuff like this that blows my mind and I need to learn. How do I get better. What resources are available to become a vba jedi. I want to, I'm a financial analyst, I'm in excel all day, and sadly my VBA skills are lacking. Any thoughts?

Comment: I guess I would recommend "learning by doing" but I also like books - would start with something like "Excel Power Programming" by John Walkenbach: that was my first intro to VBA way back when (Excel for Windows 95!)  And browse here on SO of course.

Comment: @user3075813 , Click on Tim's name above your comment. Follow the links on his profile page to see how he answered other questions. Tim fixes a lot of code here. Also, [Doug Glancy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/293078/doug-glancy), [mehow](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2140173/mehow), [Gary's Student](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2474656/garys-student), [KazJaw](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2143262/kazjaw) and the powerhouse that is [Siddharth Rout](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1140579/siddharth-rout). Who'd I accidentally miss?

Comment: @user3075813 starting list here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523102/what-is-the-best-way-to-master-vba-macros-for-ms-office-applications/7524173#7524173 best advice is to jump into the forum and answer other peoples questions.